# Dropping Link of UIButton Event for particular button on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am displaying a custom `UITableViewCell` repeatedly in a `UITableView`. There are 2 buttons on each row. I want to display all of the `UIButton`s, but I want the designated button event on particular button. How to get rid of rest of `UIButton`s events? Please assist.

**EDIT**
I am asking about any valid property if `UIButton` exhibit to disable the event.
like for selection .Selected
something like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give a tag to that button, when you create it :

```
button.tag = i;
```

Then, look at the tag of a sender:

```
UIButton *clickedButton = sender;
int buttonNo = clickedButton.tag;
```

For a particular buttonNo you can do something or do not do.